# Is there an industry adopted standard tool for Project Management for agile software development teams

Tags: agile

My understanding, is that a lot of project management software packages still work on the waterfall premise. I know there are amazing tools such as Trello but during my use, I found it more targeted at the individual tasks rather than giving an overall project view especially for more complex tasks. Things I think would be useful to see are likely/estimated time to completion, on estimate (harder with story points so maybe this only applies to hours) and reports of how the project went.

Comment on this if you think I need to change this question or make it more specific, let me know. Cheers

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! If you're just asking if there's such a thing as a single industry-standard tool, that would be on-topic, but the answer is "no." If you're asking for recommendations that meet your criteria, that's off-topic and will be closed. Please clarify your intent.

Comment: Hi there. I would have liked recommendations as well but the structure and intent of the question was to inquire about whether there was an industry standard. I see a lot of people defaulting to Microsoft Project, Trello or their own ERP/CRM/Customer build in house tool.

Answer (score 2):

A whiteboard and some sticky notes. If you can't do your process by hand, then your process is too complicated. Layering on software with lots of features, bells and whistles won't help.

But no, there isn't an industry standard. You can check out the Magic Square from Gartner to get a feel of where the industry lies on the topic. Here's a link to the 2013 edition:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/Gartner+ALM+Magic+Quadrant